# In-app purchase cancel button crashes the app without any info in the log

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, ios10

I call `SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()` and after iOS asks my password and I select "Cancel", the app will crash without log.

Sometimes the in-app purchase just crashes without more info or error. I use `IAPHelper`. Sometimes the app crashes when I call `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)`.

os: iOS 10
Xcode 8.0
language: Swift 3

Comment: It happens in simulator only, as I noted.